# Django queryset order_by greater value of two columns

Tags: sql, django, django-models, django-orm

I have the following Django model:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
      date_entered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
      date_renewed = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)
```

date_enterd is populated automatically when Entry object is created and the date_renewed filed is set to Null. Some Entries get renewed some don't (which means that some Entries will have datetime set and some will always be Null).

I need to order the queryset by the most recent time of the two, as in if an old Entry is renewed it should be the first object in the queryset, however when a new Entry is added the renewed one should go to the second place.

The Entries should be returned as follows:

```
ID   DateEntered                         DeteRenewed 
55   2014-09-02 13:39:37.698422+00:00    None
45   2014-08-06 00:00:00+00:00           2014-08-31 11:43:05.339902+00:00
54   2014-08-31 00:00:00+00:00           None
43   2014-08-06 00:00:00+00:00           2014-08-30 10:49:51.594024+00:00
51   2014-08-15 00:00:00+00:00           2014-08-29 10:49:51.594024+00:00
```

I have tried using:

```
qs.extra(select={"sort_order":"COALESC(date_entered,date_renewed)"}, order_by=["-sort_order"])
```

but this doesn't work as it picks the first non Null value.

I use Postgres in production and SQLite in the dev. I'd like to stick to Django's ORM if possible.

How can the queryset be ordered as specified above?

Comment: Have you tried ordering by DateRenewed first, then by Date Entered?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, if you did that I think all the renewed entries would come first, and only then the ones with no renewal date, even if they were more recent. user3138929, one way might be to default DateRenewed to the current date (like DateEntered), instead of null, and sort by that. You can still find the entries with no renewal by comparing DateRenewed with DateEntered. Of course, you would be storing some (or many) dates twice, unnecessarily.

Comment: Sorry for the double comment, but this occurred to me... if COALESCE picks the first non-null value, wouldn't it work if you inverted the order of its arguments, giving it date_renewed first?

Comment: Typo in question and answer. *`COALESCE`

Answer (score 0):

The COALESCE works if I swap the order of the columns as pointed out by Paulo Almeida.
Paulo also rightly pointed out that the solution propsed Burhan Khalid would not work.

The solution is:

```
qs.extra(select={"sort_order":"COALESC(date_renewed,date_entered)"}, order_by=["-sort_order"])
```